# What styles should I use in a DroneDeploy App?

Tags: android, ios, css, web-applications, dronedeploy

When writing a [DroneDeploy app](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps), what styles should I use?

The [app design guidelines](http://developer.dronedeploy.com/applications) specify that apps should follow a consistent design with the native DroneDeploy app. How do I know which styles are consistent with the native app?

*disclosure: I am a developer on the DroneDeploy team, and this is a question we regularly get from developers on the App platform.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the quickest way is to add [this CSS file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drone-deploy-plugins/templates/uikit/v1/styles.css) to the `<head>` of your `index.html` file in your app folder like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/drone-deploy-plugins/templates/uikit/v1/styles.css">
```

Specifically, to follow DroneDeploy styles you can link to the same CSS as an example app.

## Link to the same CSS as Example Apps

The above stylesheet link can be found in in the [App Design Guidelines](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/styles.html), specifically inside an example app:

> If you stick to the CSS styles guidelines below and use the [expandable app example here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drone-deploy-plugins/templates/dronedeploy-expand-example.zip), you are on the right track.

Currently, the example app links to [an external stylesheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drone-deploy-plugins/templates/uikit/v1/styles.css) that includes a set of default styles similar to a lightweight UI framework. It includes:

- Typography
- Form styles
- A basic grid-system framework with `.container`, `.row`, and `.col-*` classes as explained in the [app guidelines](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/styles.html)

As mentioned above, simply link to [this file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drone-deploy-plugins/templates/uikit/v1/styles.css) in your app as you would any other external stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you for this info, actually I was looking for it here: https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/styles/dronedeploy-ui-kit.html. Please update this page, it will help a lot of folks.

Comment: @Vadim due to a bug in safari, the UI kit is now unavailable.